# How to read from Bluetooth barcode scanner hardware device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I've been trying to get a piece of code to connect to a bluetooth bardcode reader I bought and have tried almost every library in Android Arsenal.

Currently, I am using this one: https://github.com/MacroYau/Blue2Serial

I have all permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I also request permission when the app opens:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                        android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                        android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                0);
```

I am able to connect to the scanner device from the app, it pairs up ok. But, when I scan something, I don't see the `public void onBluetoothSerialRead(String message)` method firing up. It was exactly the very same with all the other libraries I tried. I could pair up, but not read it.

Conversely, if I open a notepad type of app in the same phone and scan it, the contents are immediately written to the notepad.

The scanner device I am using is this one: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/scanners/companion-scanners/cs4070.html

Anyone with some tip to give me?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that the scanner device isn't configured for batch mode?

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang - I have no idea! Do you know how I can check that? If I simply pair it up with Android itself and can get on and scan anything I want to any notepad-type app (or Gmail, whatever). It just works.

Comment: I just went through the manual and it says "Normal Batch Mode (default) - The scanner does not batch decoded data but transmits all decoded
data to the host over Bluetooth. If the scanner is not paired to a host and you attempt to scan and decode
a bar code, the scanner emits 4 short high beeps." I haven't configured anything on that sense, so I assume I do not have batch mode configured.

Comment: I've configured the barcode reader to SPP mode and now it can read... but it's only reading parts of the barcode. Example, if the barcode is "MH1220011A" it sometimes read "MH". Sometimes "22001A" , etc, it's random. Sometimes it reads the whole thing correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few things.

(1) You are reading a 'poorly designed' 2D barcode. Some of the older 'standard' barcodes have simple checksums so lots of random data using a laser based scanner can actually result in a decoded value. If I recall correctly Interleaved 2 of 5 was one of those.

(2) If you enabled 'read all barcodes' its possible that the sub-sequence of codeword (white and black spaces) maps to a valid barcode definition. I would only enable those 2D barcode types that you would be be actually reading.

(3) On the Android side your Bluetooth serial reader isn't picking up the data fast enough. This can be mitigated with the scanner sending prefix/suffix values so that the app knows if you don't get those it was a transmission error.

Comment: Thanks, @MorrisonChang. I don't believe number 1 is a problem as I am trying multiple bar codes and all work fine if I am using the HID interface. I pair it up with Android itself with the HID profile, go to ColorNote, scan something and it's all there.

I have tried creating code for a HID profile, but was not lucky. Do you know of any android library that can deal with the HID profile?

Comment: If you go with HID, it is treated as a Bluetooth keyboard by Android. I believe you would have to alter the ROM to do any pre-filter/data modification before data gets to the app. If not custom ROM I'm assuming a kiosk type data-entry app and custom EditText views to handle the data input. Also consider licensing the Zebra SDK.

Comment: I am trying to use the Zebra SDK right now, but so far no luck. A fair number of classes missing from their .aar!